How to trim Progress Application Server agents?
Before, when I was using Classic Appserver, running the command
asbman -i <appserver> -trim
would simply trim the agents, but after switching to PAS, I can't seem to trim the PAS agents.
Is there a simpler way or a command to trim PAS server?

As noted in this comment, you can use the REST API to do things like trim an agent. This requires the installation of the oemanager webapp into the PASOE instance. There is also a command-line version that you can use if you don't want to install that webapp.
You should also be aware that PASOE changes the nature of things: in the Classic Appserver an agent contained a single ABL session. In PASOE this is fundamentally different. One agent process contains multiple ABL sessions, so operations like termination/trimming are typically not done at the agent level, but rather for individual agent sessions. There are also REST and CLI APIs for working on these.
Progress provides some additional tools for managing PASOE instances (both for sessions and other aspects), in their Iceberg repo. Take a look at https://github.com/progress/iceberg/blob/main/PAS/Management/OEManager/ABL/README.md for some more details, and for usage.

It's not that easy as with the classic appserver.
You can use REST calls to trim your agents. See here:
https://community.progress.com/s/article/How-to-trim-and-restart-PASOE-Agents-using-REST-APIs
